# What does the gene set score tell in GSA analysis?

Tags: genetics, microarray

I carrying out a gene set analysis to investigate if a list of genes are differentially expressed before and after a medical treatment (paired analysis).

The list of genes was made (a priori) by a promoter analysis, where genes that are likely to bind to a specific DNA promoter region was computationally identified. This gene set consists of  approximately 4000 genes, and is likely to contain many genes that is not a target (false positives).

I have used [GSA](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/GSA/) (Brad Efron and R. Tibshirani) on microarray data (24000 genes, maxmean statistics, paired, permutation 5000), but the result puzzles me:

```
Gene set score: -0.0325
p-value: 0.0238
```

Note that FDR is not important here, since only one gene set is being studied. Why is this gene set score so low?  What does the gene set score actually tell? Is the gene set score an averaged T score value? If so, why is p significant (<0.05)?